# PowerApps screens - Split-screen, Sidebar and Heather, Main section, Footer

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-canvas

Working on a PowerApp today, I came across 3 new "screen types" when I went to add a new screen.

[image]

Although it is fairly easy to understand how those screens are set up, I wasn't able to find Microsoft documentation on those.

They use Containers in the screen but I do not have the Container feature enabled.

As I've just noticed them, any ideas of when those new screens were added to PowerApps and release notes from Microsoft I missed?

[image]

Comment: This is more of Power Apps question than SharePoint. I will suggest you to create a new question on [Power Apps Forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/bd-p/PowerAppsForum1). You will get an answer more quickly from Power Apps experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post came on Microsoft's Power Apps blog: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-layout-containers-in-canvas-apps-make-responsive-apps-easier/

[image: Power Apps add vertical and horizontal container]